# Printing Out Python Middle Values

Tags: python, list

How would you print out the middle values in a list, for example if a list is given [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the values 2,3,4 would be printed out.

Comment: You want everything except the first and last element? Does `lst[1:-1]` not work?

Comment: No I would only like values that are in the middle of the list for example Given [1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 11, 4] the returned should be 1,1,0,-1,11

Comment: That's still everything except the first and last element, though... How many elements do you want from the middle? The middle 4 elements, the middle 5 elements?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, I am going to use it now!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(lst[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = list(range(1,6))

lst
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

lst[1:-1]
Out[3]: [2, 3, 4]
```